# getting Please install the Appropriate CrRedisrtibutable(CRRedist*.msi).........error when I run the aplication

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports-2008

I have developed a project in VS2008(C#) which contains two crystal reports, the project is working fine and crystal reports are running properly on my system. But when my friend tries to run the project on his system, then the projects runs well but when I am opening crystal reports I am getting the error like
" Please install the Appropriate CrRedisrtibutable(CRRedist*.msi) containing the correct version of the crystal report runtime......................."

We are not running packaged setup, its the whole project which we are running in framework getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Thats the problem. When you install Crystal Reports in a machine, it installs some files which are needed for creating a report in the GAC.

So when you try to run the application from some other machine make sure to install the correct runtime. You can verify the version of the dll's by inspecting the properties of the runtime files which will list the version number of the dll and cross check it with the version of the corresponding dll in the developement machine